# How to estimate parameters of exponential function with R?

Tags: r, function, parameters, exponential

I am working on an investigation on ichthyofauna (study of fishes). I need to find the condition factor of the fish.
The steps to find the condition factor are as follows:

1. W = aL^b ... (1)

Where:

- W: The weight of fish in grams.
- L: Total length of fish in centimeters.
- a: Exponent describing the rate of change of weight with length (= the intercept of the regression line on the Y axis).
- b: The slope of the regression line (also referred to as the Allometric coefficient).

2. Log w = log a + b log L ... (2)

Where:

- a: constant
- b: the regression co-efficient

3.  K = 100 w/L^b ... (3)

Where:

- W: Weight of the fish in grams
- L: The total length of the fish in centimeters
- b: The value obtained from the length-eight equation formula

I understand that to calculate K, I must first obtain the regression slope (b of 1), then the co-efficient regression (b of 2) and finally K. I need help to do it in R.
I would be very grateful for your support.
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for a very simple regression, you may want to start with a linear model, and you'd do something like this:

```
reg1 <- lm(log(W) ~ log(L), data=yourdataframename)
```

then check the summary for coefficients:

```
summary(reg1)
```

Note you don't need to take a log of the intercept because it is a column of ones essentially (but it is included implicitly unless you put '-1' in your parameters)

Comment: Hello, many for your response. However, the first thing to do is an exponential regression.

Comment: So you create a new variable then W <- a*L^b (assuming you have a, L and b in memory, otherwise yourdataframename$W <- yourdataframename$a*yourdataframename$L^yourdataframename$b) - I'm not sure how your dataset/variables are structured, it would help if you amend your post with clarification

Comment: No problem - let me know if you have any questions, would also appreciate if you mark your question as answered, cheers